# Saving file with progressBar (Windows Form Application)

Tags: c#, sql-server, progress-bar, backgroundworker, file-transfer

I have a problem in my application.

I have the following problem: I need to save a file in the database and while the file is being saved, I want to show the progress of the save. I tried doing with Threads, BackgroundWorker but none of that has been achieved.

On the internet, I have seen several examples that show the backgroundWorker or Thread but always use the Timer to perform the progressBar count.

Is there any real way I can perform this procedure and know how many bytes were saved, how many bytes left to be saved, and on that count an estimated time count and / or completion percentage?

I believe that many have already gone through this and still have doubts so who can help I will be grateful!

Thank you!

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed the code responsible for storing the file in the DB. Without it it's hard to suggest anything beyond "use a separate thread" or "use a `BackgroundWorker`"...

Comment: I no longer have my code, because all my attempts have been frustrated.

Comment: But I would like to know how to solve this problem, as I currently have to do something like this, but I have no idea where to start. I had a terrible experience with that. :/

Comment: With no code to show, it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong. Again, without that all anyone can suggest is to use any of the standard patterns: `BackgroundWorker` class, the `async / await` pattern or just a `Task`. At the very least provide the code that does something (i.e. the copy operation).